# Induced_graph Not a graph object, plotting a graph network

Tags: r, igraph

I'm learning how to plot graphs and networks using the `igraph` library in R.

I retrieved a dataset from this repository: http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon0302.html

I read the graph and I calculated the degree of the nodes. The data set contains more than 20k of nodes. Therefore I want to plot a subset of at most 3 nodes of the V1 column.

```
aws_g <- read.table("Amazon0302.txt")
aws <- graph.data.frame(aws_g, directed = T)
# Calculate degree
d <- degree(aws)
aws_g$DegreeV1 <- d[as.character(aws_g$V1)]
aws_g$DegreeV2 <- d[as.character(aws_g$V2)]
dput(aws_g[1:30,])
g2 <- induced_subgraph(aws_g, aws_g[1:7,])
g2
plot(g2)
```

The code above is giving me this error:

> Error in induced_subgraph(aws_g, aws_g[1:7, ]) : Not a graph object

**Output I want**

The graph of small set of nodes and the nodes have a different size depending on the node degree.

I'm not being able to subset the graph so it can be plotted .

aws_g object looks like:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), V2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 15L, 
0L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 7L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), DegreeV1 = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59), DegreeV2 = c(6, 7, 6, 30, 59, 7, 7, 30, 
59, 26, 7, 58, 34, 40, 18, 59, 10, 13, 12, 23, 39, 11, 26, 177, 
21, 103, 39, 298, 20, 39)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "DegreeV1", 
"DegreeV2"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How would aws_g become a graph.data.frame?  You make aws a graph.data.frame but not aws_g.

Comment: You are correct, was an error of mine. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you are referring to your vertices incorrectly within `induced_subgraph`. Try this instead:

```
g2 <- induced_subgraph(aws_g, 1:7)
plot(g2)
```

[image]